# multiple search from database in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, filter, eloquent

I want to search data from database and show in my laravel blade.
here is my controller

```
 $results = ClassModel::query();
 $results->when(request('student_id'), function($q){
      $q->where('student_id', request('student_id'));
    })
    ->when(request('student_name'),function($q){
      $q->orWhere('student_name', request('student_name'));
    })
    ->when(request('subject'), function($q){
      $q->orWhere('subject', request('subject'));
    })
    ->when(request('teacher_name'), function($q){
      $q->orWhere('teacher_name', request('teacher_name'));
    })
    ->when(request('class'), function($q){
      $q->orWhere('class', request('class'));
    });
    $records = $results->get();
    return view('class.index')->with('class', $records);
```

it works ok with few filters when I add all multiple filters it returns me empty array , I don't know why .Is that method fine or should I try any other method ?

Comment: use orWhere instead, when you use where, every field has to match, but orWhere any field can match

Comment: orwhere returns me all data means it not filtering the data

Comment: show us your current code

Comment: check updated question

Comment: why not using laravel scope? using laravel scope, it will easier to make a dynamic query with dynamic parameter. may be you can learn from this [article](https://medium.com/@janaksan_/using-scope-with-laravel-7c80dd6a2c3d)